# I'm not able to login to SF Functions account

Tags: salesforce-functions

Can you please help about the following issue i'm facing when try to connect to SF function account?

I have a trial org to test SF Functions feature and it has the SF Functions activated, I'm using the following [instructions](https://github.com/trailheadapps/functions-recipes/tree/trial/1.1/trial-config) and when i run command

`sf login functions`

it open my browser to a login page with only a button to click `login to Salesforce`

[image]

When i click that button i end up in another page with only error

> IP Address mismatched

[image]

does any one run into similar issue please?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to solve this issue; I noticed there's a proxy tool on the company laptop that was manipulating the IP somehow, but after i switched it off i was able to connect and login successfully
[image]